# React Router Renders Empty Script Tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to figure out React Router, but when I load the page I am only seeing an empty script tag being rendered. I must be doing something wrong. I have followed the guide on the react router docs page.

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var About = require('./About');
var Inbox = require('./Inbox');

var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route path="about" handler={About}/>
    <Route path="inbox" handler={Inbox}/>
  </Route>
);

var App = React.createClass({
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>App</h1>
          <RouteHandler/>
        </div>
      )
    }
});

Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
    React.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I needed to put my routes variable below App like so:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var About = require('./About');
var Inbox = require('./Inbox');

var App = React.createClass({
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>App</h1>
          <RouteHandler/>
        </div>
      )
    }
});

var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route path="about" handler={About}/>
    <Route path="inbox" handler={Inbox}/>
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
    React.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Comment: More precisely, you need to put the usage of `App` below the definition of `App`.